# What is the parallel version of dplyr::mutate?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr, tidyverse

Given that I have a very large dataframe, please advise if there is a function in R to make `dplyr::mutate` to run in parallel multicored?

Like `furrr` package where you can set the `plan` and run multicored.

Comment: perhaps you can check [multidplyr](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr)

Comment: I know @akrun but do you aware of a parallel mutate function?